# How to make UITableView appear from bottom to top when scroll?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm looking just for general scenario.The idea is when app launches user can see only first cell of UITableView at the bottom of UIViewController. When user scrolls up full table appears and when scrolls down only first cell is displayed again. Something similar like keyboard in Facebook messenger app, but with tableView. For now I added tableView as subview to scrollView, but problem is tableView appears from top to bottom, and I'm looking for solution how to make this work upside down.. So, tableView have to appear from bottom to top of UIViewController.

Comment: You should use scrollview. Add tableview inside of scrollview and use scrollview content offset value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea would be:

- Give your `UITableView` the desired frame at `viewDiDLoad` (probably the height of 1 cell, at the bottom of your `UIView`)
- Let your `UIViewController` implement `UIScrollViewDelegate`
- At `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` of `UIScrollViewDelegate` check which element is scrolling (if its your `UITableView`) and also check which direction user is scrolling
- Change the frame of the `UITableView` as you wish, you will also have to come up with some logic to block further changing of the `UITableView`'s frame (a BOOL would do good here I guess)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your correctly but, maybe, this will be helpful

I believe you can try to add zero cell (or first section header view of your `UITableView`) with transparent background. So that your first cell will be placed on the bottom of screen and `UITableView` height will be equal to screen height.

In this case, you will have only one scrolling view (`UITableView`, in particularly). Following method can be used to perform expandable animation and scroll table to top to hide zero cell when user taps on first cell:

```
[UITableView scrollRectToVisible:animated:]
```

After that you can leave `UITableView` as it is and "constrict" your table whenever you need in the same way as it was expanded before.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want to do.
In general, UITableView shows cells from top to bottom.

You can add transform in tableview:

```
tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

Then your tableview will show the cells from bottom to top and you can scroll tableview from bottom to top.
But cells will be transformed as tableview, so you have to add same transform to cells also.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    **cell.transform = tableView.transform**

    return cell
}
```

All done. Hope to helpful!